# How can I pass two parameters in jquery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I am trying to pass parameter1 and parameter2 into my update.inc.php, How can I combine them together and xmlsend() both of them. I only can pass one!

```js
function insert(){
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }else{
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status ==200){
   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 parameter1='bio='+document.getElementById('bio').value;
 parameter2='good='+document.getElementById('good').value;
 
 
 xmlhttp.open('POST','/condition_form/update.inc.php',true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 
 xmlhttp.send(parameter1);
 
 
 
}//insert()
```

Comment: Where is `jQuery` code ?

Comment: Why DONT you use `jQuery.ajax` ?

Answer (score 2):

the [send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()) method can take a param string, so you can just concatenate the 2 params using `&` like

```
xmlhttp.send(parameter1 + '&' + parameter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both parameter by using some delimitor like `;` or `#` etc. and then while reading parameter use `.split(delimitor)` to seperate the parameters. See below code

```
xmlhttp.send(parameter1+'#'+parameter2);
```

And while reading

```
 var parameter = //use method to get parameter
  var paramArray = parameter.split('#');
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ instead of writing old JS Ajax.

Still if you feel using the old system, you can do it by...

```
parameter1='bio='+document.getElementById('bio').value;
parameter2='good='+document.getElementById('good').value;
postdata = parameter1 + parameter2;
xmlhttp.send(postdata);
```

Comment: I learn from online. I actually don't know that is old JS Ajax. Will that cause any problem in new Browsers? Thanks for the link, I will look at it.

Comment: No, you won't be having any problem. But nowadays, generally people don't write raw javascript. With the hundreds of JS Library's out there, it made developers job easy and we can achieve the same functionality with fewer lines of code